# how to make button play sound of specific index

Tags: java, android

so I'm creating a program that plays specific sounds on each button click. I've created an array of songs but when I run the program all of the buttons play the first sound in the array. I'm trying to make the button play the sound of a specific index and here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    int[] songs = {R.raw.doyouspeakenglish, R.raw.goodevening, R.raw.hello};
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int current_index = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[current_index]);

        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this); 
}

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                 current_index =0;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                current_index = 1;
                mediaPlayer.start();
            case R.id.button3:
                current_index = 2;
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break; 
  } 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are getting only first sound for  MediaPlayer. So it causes you put sound only in `onCreate` method, which calls one time, when your activity is creating

You need to put  `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[current_index]);` inside `onClick` method

So you're `onClick` method will be looking somthing like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                 current_index =0;
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                current_index = 1;
            case R.id.button3:
                current_index = 2;
                break; 
  } 
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, songs[current_index]);
    mediaPlayer.start();
 }
```